# Is it possible to open a table with its columns uncollapsed?

Tags: tabulator

Is there a programmatic control to uncollapse a table whose columns open collapsed?  I am creating a simple table with column grouping---nothing responsive, in Version 4.0.

The only way I've found to uncollapse it is by specifying `headerSort:false` for at least one column, (then clicking on that control---which I don't otherwise need).

I'd like to open the table uncollapsed, from the start.

---

By way of further information, I am using these table to display (soon, edit) data stored on nodes in a graph.  Every table after the first opens fine from nodes' context menus.  (Even the first table opens fine on the second try---no difference in constructor between the two tries.)

I suspect incompatibility with some JavaScript plugin I use, because dummy tables also seem to open fine, initially, outside my application.  I have not yet been able to isolate this.

---

Per request, here is my constructor:

```json
{
  "initialSort": [
    {
      "column": "Over_Eff",
      "dir": "desc"
    },
    {
      "column": "Out_Eff",
      "dir": "desc"
    }
  ],
  "columnVertAlign": "bottom",
  "height": 220,
  "layout": "fitColumns",
  "columns": [
    {
      "title": "Parents",
      "columns": [
        {
          "title": "Out_Eff",
          "field": "Out_Eff",
          "align": "center",
          "sorter": "string",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "Over_Eff",
          "field": "Over_Eff",
          "align": "center",
          "sorter": "string",
          "headerSort": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Multi_Eff",
      "width": 150,
      "columns": [
        {
          "title": "T",
          "field": "pTrue",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "<i>F</i>",
          "field": "pFalse",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Belief",
      "columns": [
        {
          "title": "odds",
          "field": "odds",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "log<sub>2</sub> odds",
          "field": "log2odds",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Columns don't collapse by default, you have to have enabled responsiveLayout for that to happen.

Could you post a copy of your table constructor object so we can see how your table is configured. we need to know things like your layout mode in order to help you out.

Could you be more specific about what you are experiencing, how many colums do you have, do they fit in the table on load, are you looking to scroll the table?

Comment: Can you tell me how to render the table constructor.  The result of `new Tabulator` seems to be circular (won't print).  Did not find this in docs (not yet searchable).

Comment: Hi Bob, by table constructor i mean the JS object you are passing into the Tabulator function when you first create the table, it will show me how your table is setup so i can offer you help. You will be happy to hear the docs have been searchable for the last 20 hours :)

Comment: Oli, here is the constructor:

Comment: Oli, constructor is too long to paste here (~1200 characters).  Is there a better way to get it to you?  Will paste what I can here---comes up fine but collapses when I re-dock Chrome's tool pane.  ```{
  "initialSort": [
    {
      "column": "Over_Eff",
      "dir": "desc"
    },
    {
      "column": "Out_Eff",
      "dir": "desc"
    }
  ],
  "columnVertAlign": "bottom",
  "height": 220,
  "layout": "fitColumns",
  "columns": [
    {
      "title": "Out_Eff",
      "field": "Out_Eff",
      "align": "center",
      "sorter": "string",
      "headerSort": false
    }```

Comment: if you edit your original question you can post it there

Answer (score 0):

This behavior results from loading data before the DOM element is visible.  Fixing that issue has solved the problem.  (Same solution as posted in Oli Folkerd's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615772/expose-more-rows?noredirect=1#comment92354616_52615772).)