# Expose more rows?

Tags: tabulator

I see only the first 20 (of 128) data rows when I call table.setData.  How can I expose all 128?  I don't see any controls for this.  The 20 rows display with much blank space underneath, so I don't think it's an issue of room. When I open or dismiss Chrome developer tools, all the rows show up, but collapsed.  If I hit F12 (toggle developer tools) twice, everything is fine.  (This is in a stand-alone configuration, without other JavaScript plugins.)  My constructor and (truncated) data are appended.

- Tabulator v4.0.1
- Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
{
  "initialSort": [
    {
      "column": "WillCo_Eff",
      "dir": "desc"
    },
    {
      "column": "Which_Eff",
      "dir": "desc"
    },
    {
      "column": "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff",
      "dir": "desc"
    },
    {
      "column": "Roger_Eff",
      "dir": "desc"
    },
    {
      "column": "Over_Eff",
      "dir": "desc"
    },
    {
      "column": "Out_Eff",
      "dir": "desc"
    },
    {
      "column": "Any_Eff",
      "dir": "desc"
    }
  ],
  "columnVertAlign": "bottom",
  "height": 5180,
  "layout": "fitColumns",
  "columns": [
    {
      "title": "Parents",
      "columns": [
        {
          "title": "Any_Eff",
          "field": "Any_Eff",
          "align": "center",
          "sorter": "string",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "Out_Eff",
          "field": "Out_Eff",
          "align": "center",
          "sorter": "string",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "Over_Eff",
          "field": "Over_Eff",
          "align": "center",
          "sorter": "string",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "Roger_Eff",
          "field": "Roger_Eff",
          "align": "center",
          "sorter": "string",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff",
          "field": "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff",
          "align": "center",
          "sorter": "string",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "Which_Eff",
          "field": "Which_Eff",
          "align": "center",
          "sorter": "string",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "WillCo_Eff",
          "field": "WillCo_Eff",
          "align": "center",
          "sorter": "string",
          "headerSort": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Multi_1_Eff",
      "width": 150,
      "columns": [
        {
          "title": "T",
          "field": "pTrue",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "<i>F</i>",
          "field": "pFalse",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Belief",
      "columns": [
        {
          "title": "odds",
          "field": "odds",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        },
        {
          "title": "log<sub>2</sub> odds",
          "field": "log2odds",
          "align": "center",
          "headerSort": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

foo.js:273

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "pTrue": 0.9,
    "pFalse": 0.09999999999999998,
    "odds": 9.000000000000002,
    "log2odds": 3.1699250014423126,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "pTrue": 0,
    "pFalse": 1,
    "odds": 0,
    "log2odds": null,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "T",
    "Over_Eff": "F",
    "Roger_Eff": "F",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "F",
    "Which_Eff": "F",
    "WillCo_Eff": "F"
  },
  {
    "id": 32,
    "pTrue": 0.1125,
    "pFalse": 0.8875,
    "odds": 0.1267605633802817,
    "log2odds": -2.9798221180623696,
    "Any_Eff": "T",
    "Out_Eff": "F",
    "Over_Eff": "T",
    "Roger_Eff": "T",
    "VeryVeryVeryLongWay_Eff": "T",
    "Which_Eff": "T",
    "WillCo_Eff": "T"
  }
]
```

Comment: is your table hidden when it is first created? that would explain why it suddenly works when you open your console and the browser resizes. Tabulator has to be visible when data is loaded into it so it can no how to layout the table as invisible elements have no height or width in the DOM. if you call the ***redraw*** function on the table as soon as it is visible that will fix your issue.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have been the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have set your table height to an enormous value of 5180px so it has probably overflowed the height of the container.

If you set it to a smaller value, say 300, or you set it to "100%" then it will only take up that much space and a scroll bar will appear.

```
"height": 300,
```

or

```
"height": "100%",
```

Alternatively, if you want to handle the scroll behavior if you specify no height it will take the full height of all the rows in the table.

Comment: With `height:500`, I get only 20 rows.  With `height:"100%"`, I get all the rows, but with columns collapsed.  With no `height`, I get all rows, uncollapsed, but of course no scroll bar (which would be handy).

Comment: Im unsure what you are after, as along as a height is set you  will get a scroll bar if the height of the rows exceeds the table

Answer (score 0):

See Oli Folkerd's comment---problem was that the table's DOM element was not visible when the table was created.